# Conventional unit cell and point group symmetries?

Tags: solid-state-physics, symmetry, group-theory, crystals, lattice-model

A definition of a conventional unit cell of a lattice is one that contains the same point group symmetries as the overall lattice and is the smallest such cell.

I can understand how a (infinite) lattice can have a point group symmetry about any lattice point such as rotational symmetry, mirror symmetry etc.

But I cannot see the same for a unit cell. Please can someone explain how we go about comparing the point group symmetries of a unit cell to that of an overall lattice? (e.g. what points do we use, for a cell what exactly is meant by a symmetry when most transformations move it from its original position etc...)

**Edit**

Consider the following diagram of a simple 2d cubic lattice:
[image]

In this diagram their is a unit cell in green. This cell clearly shares a the symmetry of reflection through the line A with the lattice. However the lattice is also symmetric by reflection through the line B but the unit cell is not even though for the lattice it is a point group symmetry of one of the lattice points within the unit cell. I would therefore say that this unit cell and the lattice do not share the same symmetry and therefore this unit cell is not a conventional unit cell. I however know (/am pretty confident) that this is indeed a conventional unit cell, given the above definition I, however cannot cell how this holds and where my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: 'Conventional unit cell' is not a precise thing, in that there are many 'conventional' unit cells so named by different authors. Now, a Wigner-Seitz unit cell, that perhaps you can understand given Wigner's broad use of group theory.

Comment: @JonCuster Although the term 'Conventional Unit Cell' may not be precise I think that my definition given above is, and for a given lattice specifies a unique cell (I have changed it slightly since you posted your comment).

Comment: Concerning your final phrase, recall that point groups operations do not translate the object.  The transformations do not move the cell.

Comment: @garyp consider a cube, unless you rotate it about its center and by very specific amounts, the cube will occupy a different space (i.e. its corners before and after rotation will not line up).

Comment: Ok, but that's not a group operation.  So I guess I don't understand why you bring up this possibility.  I'm worried that I do not understand your question.

Comment: @garyp I guess what I am confused about is how we identify the unit cell with the same symmetry as the crystal and what it exactly means for a unit cell to have the same symmetry as the crystal.

Comment: Do we say for example... "the point group symmetries of the unit cell about its center must be the same as the point group symmetries of the crystal about any lattice point."?

Comment: If we take a 3D version of your question, does the problem go away if we take a cubic unit cell?

Answer (score 3):

> A definition of a conventional unit cell of a lattice is one that contains the same point group symmetries as the overall lattice and is the smallest such cell.

I don't think this is the definition of a "conventional unit cell".

The "smallest cell" that fully describes any structure is the *primitive* cell, which is the smallest cell that contains only one lattice point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_cell

The important symmetries for the primitive cell are the translational symmetries, which are part of the space group symmetry of the lattice, not the point group symmetry. Because the definition of the primitive cell does not specify the position of the cell origin with respect to the contained lattice point, the *point group* symmetry of a primitive cell is not uniquely defined, and depends on the choice of cell origin. You may, or may not, be able to find point group symmetry operations within a given cell that you would expect from looking at the full crystal.

Comment: I'd like to add that there is a procedure to find the primitive cell called the Wigner-Seitz procedure. See [this webpage](https://www.physics-in-a-nutshell.com/article/5/unit-cell-primitive-cell-and-wigner-seitz-cell), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

The unit cell is a 3D figure which possess certain symetry (e.g. cube, tetragon etc.). The unit cell is selected after you have found out what is the symmetry of the crystal, and it is selected in a way that it has the symmetry of the crystal (can be rather complicated, like [here](http://images.slideplayer.com/14/4358313/slides/slide_5.jpg)). You cannot build unit cell if you don't know what your crystal look like (just from the number of atoms, etc.). With a given unit cell you can reproduce your crystal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You said "it is selected in a way that it has the symmetry of the crystal", this is the crux of my question. I cannot see how we compare the symmetry of the unit cell with the infinite crystal. I would appreciate it if you could please go into more depth surrounding this statement. Also see the edits to the question above (I have tried to clarify more my problems).

Comment: After I've read your edit, I guess I can see what is missing. The key thing is that we are considering POINT groups, i.e. you should care that all the elements of the group are related to the same point. For the unit cell this is typically a "center" of the unit cell, i.e. its' most symmetric point (center of the square in your case). Now if you will draw the horizontal line through the center of the cell both cell, and lattice will be symmetric with respect to reflection.

Comment: In other words when you are looking for a symmetry element in your lattice or unit cell, you should ask the question "Can I find a point/line with respect to which my unit cell/lattice will possess this symmetry?".
Crude example of how your previous way of thinking will not work on lattice: In your drawing - another symmetry element is rotation by Pi/4. If I will randomly select any point (let say 1/5 of the lattice constant away from point A ) my lattice will not be symmetric to rotation by Pi/4. But if I will look for a point for which it does, I will find some.

Comment: Finally, in general case it can be quite non-obvious to draw a unit cell, or to find a point in the lattice for which all the symmetries are respected. I failed my first attempt on group theory exam, because I could not find one:)

Comment: An extra comment: there is a certain freedom of choice of the unit cell as you might know, which does not limit the generality. For instance you may place center of the square in the B point. In this case you will still have horizontal and diagonal reflection planes, though the diagonal now will be required to pass through B.

Comment: Are we saying that we find the point group symmetry of the unit cell at a point P (which is likely to be the center) and if the lattice has the same point group symmetry about P then this unit cell is called conventional?

Comment: I guess there is a certain difference in terminology across the people (maybe I am just not aware of the proper one). For instance I've been taught that primitive cells do not necessarily possess lattice symmetry but have the smallest possible volume, while unit cells do (like Wigner-Seitz). Now conventional unit cell is the one which is built on the Bravais vectors and have full symmetry of the lattice. 
I typically don't say primitive unit cell (unless it is Wigner-Seitz), though I know people do (may be because I have Russian education).

Comment: So again in the terminology I am used to any unit cell should have the symmetry of the lattice, but conventional is build on the Bravais vectors.

Comment: I think this has the cart before the horse so to speak. We define a unit cell according to how we want to work with the lattice. We may desire a specific set of symmetry rules or we may desire a specific operational convention. Better said, the unit cell is not revealed by the symmetry of the lattice, the unit cell may be chosen to reveal a specific set of symmetries in the overall lattice. The primitive unit cell and cubic unit cell conventions of the BCC or FCC lattices come to mind as examples.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your difficulty is that you are not choosing a point about which to define your symmetry operations (after all, they are called *point* symmetries).  In the case of your specific square, the symmetry operations are defined w/r to the center of the square.

[image]

This makes it clear that the reflections - indicated in blue or red - are about planes going through the symmetry point.  In particular, a reflection about the horizontal axis interchange $(12)\leftrightarrow (43)$.

If you choose an atom in the square as symmetry point, then you will need to use (discrete) translations to bring the transformed square back to its original position.  These translations are also included in the symmetry group of the *lattice* so no real harm is done since any two cells are equivalent.

There are several good sources on this but one I like is

> A.W. Joshi, *Elements of group theory for physicists*.

Comment: Isn't reflection a symmetry which is defined through a line?

Comment: yes but this line goes through the symmetry point.